# If some program is not working in Ubuntu, how to uninstall and reinstall

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation, reinstall

I'd be specially interested in a solution that covers the dependencies of this program, and not only the program as such.

I have several programs that don't work after I updated to Ubuntu 13.04 from 12.10; and I suspect that they have a common problem in some package that all use.

Note: what's not working is Evolution, Unity Tweaks, Ubuntu Tweaks, and Bleach (it freezes after running).

I've tried apt-get purge and install, to no avail. I wonder whether the problem is solvable, maybe these programs won't run in Ubuntu 13.04.

I get following messages:

```
(evolution:25416): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_entry_set_text: assertion `text != NULL' failed

(evolution:25416): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_entry_set_text: assertion `text != NULL' failed

(evolution:25416): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_entry_set_text: assertion `text != NULL' failed

(evolution:25416): Gtk-WARNING **: Attempting to read the recently used resources file at `/home/k4/.local/share/recently-used.xbel', but the parser failed: Failed to open file '/home/k4/.local/share/recently-used.xbel': Permission denied.

(evolution:25416): IBUS-WARNING **: The owner of /home/k4/.config/ibus/bus is not k4!
```

and then I get the

```
segmentation fault (core dumped).
```

message (after it asks me to configure the email).

Comment: I don't agree it may be better on askubuntu, since the question applies to all Debian derivatives, not just Ubuntu.

Comment: You can't reinstall all the packages the package depend upon. For instance, one of them will be the `libc`, and if you uninstall that one, that will break everything.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few obvious things from the errors thrown here that are problematic:

1) `/home/k4/.local/share/recently-used.xbel` is not apparently able to be read correctly by the user k4 as it should be (permission denied). Check that the appropriate permissions are enabled for user k4.

2) `The owner of /home/k4/.config/ibus/bus is not k4!` - that's a big pointer to an issue with ownership in you k4 user's folders and configuration for ibus. Should probably check ownership of same.

When upgrading, find it simpler to remove old configuration files and let the system place them in the new install myself, but your mileage may vary.

Would say that permissions/ownership are where the issues lie in this instance and providing `k4` with the correct permissions and ownership of that user's folder will correct the issue. Why a two-character user is chosen, don't know, but that's the issue here.

Answer (score 0):

I think chances that those programs really doesn't work in Ubuntu 13.04 are very low.

I bet that old config files breaks the functioning of the mentioned programs. To test upon this cause you should create a new user with

```
sudo useradd -d /home/testusr -s /bin/bash -m testusr
sudo passwd myuser
```

After that login as `testusr` and start the programs. I'm sure that the programs are working in the new `testusr` environment.

Comment: Well, I wouldn't mind of getting rid of my config files. Can't I tell Ubuntu to delete them? (BTW, I thought that was the idea of apt-get purge, to get rid of something completely).

Comment: `apt-get purge` doesn't touch config files in your `$HOME` dir. You have to delete them on your own. Just type `ls -d .*` and look for names that are related to the stated programs. Delete them with a simple `rm -r`.

Comment: Did that (with evolution). They config files were in .config. Installed again, but nothing. I still get a segmentation fault (core dumped) error.

Comment: @juan could you add the complete error at your question? seems like some deeper problem.

Comment: @Braiam: added extra info.

Comment: try `sudo chown k4 /home/k4/.local/share/recently-used.xbel /home/k4/.config/ibus/bus`